# Node.js API endpoint for PostgreSQL database backup produces empty SQL file

Tags: postgresql, docker, express, prisma

I have an API endpoint in my Node.js application that should perform a backup of my PostgreSQL database and return the result as an SQL file. The API uses the dockerode library to connect to a PostgreSQL container and run the pg_dump command to create the backup. The API sets the response headers to indicate that the result is a download, and pipes the output from the pg_dump command to the response. However, the resulting SQL file is always empty.
Here is the relevant code:
`router.post(
"/backup",
isSuperAdmin,
async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
try {
const connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || "";
const connectionParams = parse(connectionString);

```
      // Replace this with the container name or ID of your Postgres container
      const postgresContainerName = "/bookmystay-api-db";

      // Find the Postgres container
      const containers = await docker.listContainers();
      const postgresContainerInfo = containers.find(
        (container) =>
          container.Names && container.Names.includes(postgresContainerName)
      );

      if (!postgresContainerInfo) {
        console.log("Postgres container not found");
        res.status(500).send("Postgres container not found");
        return;
      }

      // Create an exec instance with the pg_dump command
      const execOptions = {
        Cmd: [
          "pg_dump",
          "-U",
          String(connectionParams.user),
          "-h",
          String(connectionParams.host),
          "-p",
          String(connectionParams.port),
          "-d",
          String(connectionParams.database),
        ],
      };

      console.log(execOptions.Cmd.join(" "));

      const exec = await docker
        .getContainer(postgresContainerInfo.Id)
        .exec(execOptions);

      // Run the exec instance and capture the output as a stream
      const stream = await exec.start({ Tty: false });

      console.log("Backup stream started");

      if (stream) {
        console.log("Backup stream has data");

        // Set the response headers to indicate that this is a download
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=backup.sql");

        // Pipe the stream to the response
        stream.pipe(res);
      } else {
        console.log("Backup stream is empty");
        res.status(500).send("Error backing up the database");
      }
      console.log("Database backup completed");
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  }
);`
```

I have logged the output from the pg_dump command and it appears to be running correctly, but the resulting SQL file is always empty. I have tried several different approaches to writing the data to the response, but have had no luck. Can anyone help me figure out why the SQL file